# How to fix jstl cforeach tag not rendering in Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I have set up Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.62 (1.7.2) in Netbeans and the server runs fine. I added these jars in $CATALINA_HOME/lib:

- javaee-api-6.0-6.jar
- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar

I have the proper configuration in context.xml and web.xml for accessing the database using JDBC for Mysql because i'm able to see the data with these JSTL tags:

```
<c:forEach var="cartItem" items="${cart.items}" varStatus="iter">
               <c:set var="product" value="${cartItem.product}"/>

            <div id="product_container_cart" class="lazyload">

            <div class="product_img_container">
                <div id="product_image"><a href="viewProduct?${product.id}">
                                <img class="cart_img" alt="" src="${initParam.productGalleryImagePath}${product.id} (1).jpg" /></a></div>
            </div>
                                <div class="product_name_container">
                                    <div style="text-align:center;" id="product_name"><a class="category_links" href="viewProduct?${product.id}">${product.name}</a></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="product_price_container">
                                    <div id="product_price" style="text-align:center;" >$${product.price}</div></div>

                <div id="button_wrapper_cart">

                    <div id="add_toList_cart"><form id="wishlistFormCart" action="addToWishlist" method="post">
          <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">

          <input id="submit_list_cart" class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToWishlist'/>" type="submit">
        </form></div>

                <div id="updateCart">

                    <form id="updateForm" action="updateCart" method="post">
                                                <input type="hidden"
                                                       name="productId"
                                                       value="${product.id}">

                                                <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                                                <input type="text"

                                                       maxlength="2"
                                                       size="2"
                                                       value="${cartItem.quantity}"
                                                       name="quantity"
                                                       style="margin:0px">

                                                <input class="updateButton"  type="submit"
                                                       name="submit"
                                                           onclick="updatedCart()"
                                                       value="<fmt:message key='update'/>">

                                            </form>
                </div>


                </div>

            </div>
          </c:forEach>
```

but with these tags, the data do NOT display:

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" varStatus="iter">

            <div id="product_container" class="lazyload">

            <div class="product_img_container">
                <div id="product_image"><a href="viewProduct?${product.id}">
                                <img class="img" alt="" src="${initParam.productGalleryImagePath}${product.id} (1).jpg" /></a></div>
            </div>
                                <div class="product_name_container">
                                    <div id="product_name"><a class="category_links" href="viewProduct?${product.id}">${product.name}</a></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="product_price_container">
                                    <div id="product_price">$${product.price}</div></div>

                <div id="button_wrapper_category">
                <div id="add_toList">

                    <form id="wishlistForm" action="addToWishlist" method="post">
          <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">

          <input id="submit_list" class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToWishlist'/>" type="submit">
        </form></div>

                <div id="add_toCart">

                    <form id="cartForm" action="addToCart" method="post">


          <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">
          <input id="submit_cart" class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>" type="submit">


                    </form></div>
                </div>

            </div>
          </c:forEach>
```

Any idea why? I tested the connection to the database by trying to display simple product ids with this:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<% Connection connection = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/<DATABASE NAME>?user=<USERNAME>&password=<PASSWORD>");
Statement sql = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet result = sql.executeQuery("SELECT product FROM category_has_product");
while(result.next() )
{
out.println(result.getString("product_id") + "<br />");
} %>
```

I was able to display all the product IDs which is a good sign that Tomcat can successfully connect to the DB and retrieve requested data. So what is the issue with the second tag?

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be:

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" varStatus="iter">
```

Check if you binding this variable **categoryProducts** to **request** object and it has content

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean? What should be the problem?

Comment: @Rachid I think you should debug the method that retrieves the list of categoryProducts. Make sure the list is not empty.

If that's ok, you can check if you add an object name "categoryProducts" that store a list of product to request object. Because the jsp will read this object from the request

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have little knowledge of Tomcat since I just migrated from GlassFish. The Servlet and the JSTL tag (cforEach) used to work great with Fish. It's very different with Tomcat. My app used to work with no conflict.

Comment: this is the request in the Servlet:
        `if (userPath.equals("/category")) {

            String categoryId = request.getQueryString();
            if (categoryId != null) {
               
                selectedCategory = categoryFacade.find(Short.parseShort(categoryId));
                
                session.setAttribute("selectedCategory", selectedCategory);
                
                categoryProducts = selectedCategory.getProductCollection();
                
                session.setAttribute("categoryProducts", categoryProducts);
            }`